# WPF BindingExpression System.Windows.Data Error: Need filename or class name (Dependency Injection/MEF)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

Is there a way to see which UserControl/Window/etc is being instantiated when these errors are happening?

A typical error looks like this:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'BackgroundColor' property not found on 'object' ''MapContainerViewModel' (HashCode=25350572)'. BindingExpression:Path=BackgroundColor; DataItem='MapContainerViewModel' (HashCode=25350572); target element is 'SolidColorBrush' (HashCode=35109313); target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')
```

Problem? Where is it happening? In which XAML file? In which class?

**Doesn't it seem bizarre that you get a list of symptoms, but not the patient's name?**

In a small project I would probably know where to look. I'm currently refactoring an MVVM project with hundreds of Windows/UserControls, many of which have similar looking Binding Paths.

So I have to do an "Entire Solution" search for the property names and come up with a list of candidates (UserControls/Windows) that may have caused the Binding error when they were instantiated.

Another option would be to have Visual Studio break and show me the XAML as soon as a System.Windows.Data error occurs. Following tutorials like [this one](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/12/11/wpf-data-binding-debug/), I can get the code to break--but it doesn't indicate any XAML or class name. The stack trace shows nothing--as the controls are being automatically created via MEF.

Thanks for any help.
Chad.

**UPDATED:**

Live Visual Tree doesn't work in this case, because the UserControls/Windows in question are sitting in an MEF container and aren't attached.

Any visual approach won't work because the views/datacontexts (view models, in this case) were instantiated via MEF (DI pattern) and are waiting to be added to the visual tree.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The debugger is not going to help you very much with XAML.  This is because XAML is declarative while the debugger is designed for imperative code.  For WPF you need to rely on a different tool set, specifically the Live Visual Tree and the Live Property Explorer in VS2017.

Here is a simple WPF app with a few textbox controls.

[image]

One of the text box controls is not working.  How do I find it?  First open the Live visual tree.  Click the enable selection button in the WPF tool bar (the second button).  Then select the control which is not working.  The live visual tree will select the control.

[image]

Now select the TextBox parent control in the Live Visual Tree (FirstValueField).  Now open the Live Property Explorer.

[image]

Note the yellow box around the Text property.  This is where the error is.  Click to the right of the property field and select "Go To Source".

[image]

So here is where the error is.  You can see where I changed the code to introduce the error.

This is the general approach to debugging WPF, XAML or any declarative code: (1) give up on the debugger...it will simply get in the way; (2) learn how to use the fit-for-purpose tools to find errors; (3) if that doesn't work, use print statements.

In my experience the WPF tools are excellent for finding common errors.  The more complex your WPF becomes however, the more you will need to embed code to diagnose and identify the problem.

Comment: Thank you. That can be useful in a different case. However my situation is a little different. The application seems to instantiate all of its controls before they are shown by iterating through the Lazy<> List of imports right before the main window is shown. Not all of the controls are shown; but I think the reason it was done this way was that as soon as a particular control was needed, the application would display it. 

The way you describe here wouldn't help much in this case because the controls simply aren't being displayed when the errors occur.

Thank you though.

Comment: My advice stands.  You need to be using the Live Visual Tree and the Live Property Explorer to find problems.  It doesn't matter whether the controls are visible or not, the Live Visual Tree will show them.  You seem to imply with your comment that you are looking for another way to diagnose problems. There is no other way.

Comment: Sorry if there's any misunderstanding; I haven't seen the tools operate when there are no windows visible. If the controls are just living inside an MEF container and aren't being shown, how would they appear in the Visual Tree?

Comment: I don't think you understand. 

The controls aren't attached anywhere to any visible window. They're not collapsed; they're not hidden. They're sitting in an MEF container as objects that haven't been rendered yet. 

I can go through the process of showing all 100 or so controls to catch the culprit, but it would be easier to do as I said before--just look at the Binding property, search the solution for possible matches, and find the control/window that way.

It just seems bizarre that a System.Windows.Data error wouldn't give the name of the Window/User control in the error itself.

Comment: For the record, I did try the Visual Tree approach. No dice. Nothing shows because nothing is attached to the main window. Updated question with screenshot.

Comment: Indeed it is hard for me to envision the environment in which you are working.  MEF is a component technology.  The way I would approach this refactoring project is to build harnesses to individual test the components.  If the way the components connect to the rest of the system is a problem then I would create shims to suss out the data binding problems.  The point is this:  if the tools are not working in your current environment, then change the environment so the tools begin working.  Otherwise, it seems to me, you are simply grasping at straws.